# JIRA/GreenHopper: How to allow users to rank issues, but not change the fixVersion?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

For reasons I won't go into here I need to stop developers from changing the Fix Version in JIRA without preventing them from changing the Green Hopper Ranking.

This is slightly complicated as Greenhopper allows you to change whether you are using the Schedule Issues or Resolve Issues permission for this stuff.

I've tried the following:

- Set GH to use the Resolve Issues permission and revoked the Resolve Issues permission. This prevents users from changing both fields.
- Set GH to use the Schedule Issues permission and revoked the Resolve Issues permission. This allows editing of Ranking, and blocks changing the Fix Version in the JIRA screens, so far so good. However it is still possible to change the Fix Version in the Green Hopper Planning board.
- I've also investigated removing the Fix Version field from the JIRA screens, however you can still always change it in GH.

I'm out of ideas, so I'm hoping someone out there has worked out the answer for me :)

Forgot to mention - I'm using JIRA 4.1.2 with GH 5.1

Comment: Did I miss anything in your situation in my answer? Anything I could do to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, what you describe can't be done. Atlassian has made clear that they won't be providing field level security as outlined in [JIRA-1330](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-1330).

That said, control of who can and can't set the fixVersion field is controlled by the [Resolve Issue permission](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=149834) as noted here, though it appears you have gone down that route.

My question to you: are you using the fixVersion field? If so, how are you using it and when is it set? The answer to that is key to figuring out the right way to go.

A few possible ways to address this issue:

- Control it via a workflow as outlined in this [article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=149834)
- Control it via a template as outlined in this [article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Using+Templates+to+control+edit+of+an+issue)
- See if the [Field Security Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.quisapps.jira.jfs) might meet your needs

Having worked with JIRA long enough, I do know that I could cobble something together to make this a reality. It just is going to take time. For example, you might be able to use the scripting plugin to reset the fixVersion field if it has been edited by anyone without the permission to change it.

Depending on how important this is to you, you might want to retain a JIRA Consultant to come up with a solution for your need.